# Trouble with wakeonlan with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, wakeonlan

I've followed the instructions on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WakeOnLan but i'm having difficulty getting it working. My BIOS is enabled for wake on lan and i've been able to do it using windows hibernate/sleep with the same NIC.

Answer (score 12):

If the cause is WoL settings not being persistent after reboot as explained in the previous answer, there is a simpler solution, which is posted here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1051894/883129

- Make sure you have `ethtool` and `wakeonlan` installed.
- Create `/etc/network/if-up.d/wol_fix` file with the following content:

  ```bsh
  #!/bin/sh
  /sbin/ethtool -s [card] wol g
  ```

  where [card] is the name of your ethernet adapter, such as `eth0`, `enp4s0` etc. (you can check this with `ifconfig` command).
- Then run:

  ```
  sudo chmod +x /etc/network/if-up.d/wol_fix
  ```

Comment: After trying a lot of options, this answer was the only that really worked.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu allows [Netplan](https://netplan.io/examples) for configuration. Look for the interface entry in `/etc/netplan/*.yaml` and enable `wakeonlan`. E.g.

```yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: true
      wakeonlan: true
```

[See details](https://netplan.io/reference).

Run 'netplan apply' after changes. To see the current setup 'netplan get all'

The filename can differ, check for `01-netcfg.yaml` and others. One can also create a new one.

Comment: Out of the suggested solutions in this thread, this was the only one that worked for me on Ubuntu Server 20.04

Comment: Ok so my ubuntu 22.04 system netplan does not recognize the command ethernets: What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

I recently upgraded to Linux Mint 20.  After re-installing the "wakeonlan" package I noticed it was not working.  It turned out that upon shutdown, the wakeonlan option was being disabled.  Here's how I worked around it.

On the computer you want to be able to wake up remotely...

Become root...

```
sudo su
```

Install the wakeonlan program on the computer you want to be able to wake up remotely.

```
apt install wakeonlan
```

Find your ethernet adapter, mine was called 'enp10s0' (usually called 'eth0').

```
ifconfig -a
```

Check the ethernet adapter to see what "Wake-on" is set to.  See below link for diffent options and what they mean.
https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Wake_On_LAN_under_Linux

```
ethtool enp10s0
```

Non-interactive creation of script which will set the "Wake-on" option to "g" which means "Wake on MagicPacket".  For the next step (systemd) to work correctly, you must have the she-bang line included on the first line of the file.

```
cat >> /root/wol_fix.sh <<EOF
#!/bin/bash
ethtool -s enp10s0 wol g
EOF
```

Set correct permissions for the fix script.

```
chmod 755 /root/wol_fix.sh
```

Non-interactive creation of script which will run on boot to run the fixing script.

```
cat >> /etc/systemd/system/wol_fix.service <<EOF
[Unit]
Description=Fix WakeOnLAN being reset to disabled on shutdown

[Service]
ExecStart=/root/wol_fix.sh
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
EOF
```

Reload the systemd manager configuration.

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

Enable to wol_fix service script.

```
systemctl enable wol_fix.service
```

NOTE: must reboot for the on-boot script to take effect.  Or you can run the /root/wol_fix.sh script manually this time only before your next shutdown or reboot.

```
reboot
```

On computer you want to use to remotely wake up your other computer...

```
# [another_computer]$
```

Non-interactive creation of script to wake up computers on network.  The "255" means only broadcast to a specific subset of the IP range on the local network.

```
cat >> /home/$USER/wakeuppc.sh <<EOF
wakeonlan -i 192.168.1.255 <MAC ADDRESS>
EOF
```

Add execute permisson for the wakeonlan caller script.

```
chmod +x /home/$USER/wakeuppc.sh
```

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1253519/trying-to-configure-wake-on-lan-with-ethtool-on-ubuntu-20-04#comment2303889_1253797 was helpful for me. I still can't get `wakeonlan -i 192.168.1.255 <MAC ADDRESS>` to do anything though. No effect.

Comment: This worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the hint to the `tlp.conf`.

This was the reason why my WOL was not working.

Be sure to uncomment the `WOL_DISABLE` setting and set it to NO:

```
# Disable wake on LAN: Y/N.
# Default: Y  #
WOL_DISABLE=N
```

Comment: Kindly add qualifiers as to *why* this solves the problem. In this case, TLP is a utility to control *ThinkPad* power related features, which is important to include in an answer.

Comment: I don't have a Thinkpad nor a laptop, but this solved it for me, I have no clue though why it solved it nor why it was installed in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem... I tried all the possible solutions and noone worked for me. Finally I discovered that my problem was related to the TLP. In its config, file tlp.conf in /etc/ folder, there is the deactivation of the wol service so after I changed there the wol service  started working again.

Comment: Thanks, this solved it for me!

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1142470/trouble-with-wake-on-lan-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Kindly add qualifiers as to *why* this solves the problem. E.g., TLP is a utility to control *ThinkPad* power related features; if you are using a *ThinkPad* laptop, this setting might disable WoL.