# Trying to configure Wake On Lan with ethtool on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, lan, wakeup

I've started to configure wake on lan on my Ubuntu 20.04. Turns out it doesn't working yet.
First, I've followed this tutorial: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-enable-wake-on-lan-in-ubuntu-server-18-04/

So, when I run `sudo systemctl is-enabled wol.service` I get `enabled`.

But, when I run `ethtool <my_iface>` I get (at the end of the list):

```
Cannot get wake-on-lan settings: Operation not permitted
    Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
                   drv probe ifdown ifup
    Link detected: yes
```

My driver is r8169 and the firmware version is rtl8411-1_0.0.3 06/18/12

Any ideias? Thx.

Answer (score 2):

Did you run the `ethtool` command as root? If not, use `sudo`.

Comment: Thanks. `sudo ethtool enp3s0` for me shows "Supports Wake-on: pumbg
        Wake-on: g"

Answer (score 2):

Actually, running the specific command "ethtool <my_iface>" with sudo, i get a different status at "wake-on" parameter, but the same error code:

```
Wake-on: g
    Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
                   drv probe ifdown ifup
```