# wakeonlan with Ubuntu 20.10 stopped working

Tags: systemd, 20.10, wakeonlan

I was using succesfully for weeks this wake on lan script https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-enable-wake-on-lan-in-ubuntu-server-18-04/ with Ubuntu 20.10.

Since a couple of days, the WOL function does not work anymore. Not sure if it was due to a linux kernel upgrade or something similar.

Did anyone else experience something similar? Or do you have a suggestion on how to debug it?

systemctl status wol.service reports that the service is enabled:

```
● wol.service - Configure Wake On LAN
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/wol.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Fri 2021-02-05 13:13:29 CET; 3min 36s ago
    Process: 2484 ExecStart=/sbin/ethtool -s eno1 wol g (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 2484 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

feb 05 13:13:29  systemd[1]: Starting Configure Wake On LAN...
feb 05 13:13:29  systemd[1]: Finished Configure Wake On LAN.
```

But then, the status is disabled:

```
sudo ethtool eno1 | grep Wake
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: d
```

If I call in the terminal by hand /sbin/ethtool -s eno1 wol g, then it is enabled:

```
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: g
```

But immediately after a systemctl suspend, I cannot wake it up remotely, and if I wake it up by keyboard, it gets reset to Wake-on: d

Any ideas of how this problem suddenly appeared? I did not modify the BIOS, it is still with WakeUp Event enabled. Maybe some kernel upgrade issues?

Note: after suspending or powering off, the LEDs on the network card completely stop blinking, even if the ethernet cable is plugged. This was not the case one week before.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Have you tried [one of the two solutions posted here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1244785/trouble-with-wakeonlan-with-ubuntu-20-04)?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I tried both of them. But it looks like a different issue. In my case, it used to work without problems on Ubuntu 20.10. In their case, it looks like it was a first-time config issue?

Comment: I ended up doing a fresh 20.04 install and it's working now without issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved it for me:

- Write `WOL_DISABLE=N` in the file `/etc/tlp.conf`

This solution is adapted from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1420717).

Comment: You should add qualifiers as to *why* this solves the problem. In this case, TLP is a utility to control *ThinkPad* power related features, thus this answer is likely only relevant for owners of *ThinkPad* laptops using the `tlp` battery saving utility

Comment: Mmm i don't have a thinkpad, neither a laptop. It's a desktop computer. Not sure how tlp got installed or what program made it end up here. I do not know either why changing it solved the problem, but it did.

Comment: Interesting. Care to share what network adapter you are using? E.g., by running `sudo dmesg  | grep -I ethernet`?

Comment: Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
driver: igb
version: 5.15.0-48-generic
firmware-version:  0. 6-1