# Wake-on-LAN broken after 22.04 update

Tags: networking, 22.04, bios, wakeonlan

I've recently updated one of my machines from Ubuntu 21.10 to 22.04
without any major issues. However, it seems like my Wake-on-LAN configuration
has broken down somehow.

WoL is enabled at the BIOS/UEFI level and a `systemd` service is run during
boot:

```
[Unit]
Description=Enable Wake-up on LAN

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/sbin/ethtool -s %i wol g

[Install]
WantedBy=basic.target
```

Now however, this command just yields:

```
netlink error: Operation not supported
```

And even when checking with `ethtool` manually by running:

```
sudo ethtool enp4s0
```

There's no mention of `Wake-On:` anymore. Has something changed in 22.04 to the
network stack that disables WoL support? Or is there something I can do to debug
this further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the newer kernel disables WoL on some adapters. Depending on your adapter that can be the case. See:

- [Wake-on-LAN quit working with latest kernel (Bionic)](https://askubuntu.com/a/1052087)
- r8169

  - [Wake-on-LAN stopped working with 4.15.0-24 kernel](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1779899)
  - [r8169 ethernet card don't work after returning from suspension](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1752772)
- AR8161:

  - [[regression] Wake-on-LAN broken in alx (AR8161)](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=61651)
  - Some patches that may work, also depending on kernel version: https://github.com/AMV007/alx_dkms_installer

I have a AR8161 (Qualcomm Atheros AR816x/AR817x) and the same issue after upgrading Ubuntu from 20.04 to 22.04. You can check your adapter with `sudo dmesg  | grep -i ethernet`.

Maybe a newer kernel will fix this or there are patches around which work.

Answer (score 3):

I solved the issue on a Qualcomm Atheros AR816x/AR817x adapter. **Use at own risk!**

I've done this fully remote on the affected machine with success.

```
sudo dmesg  | grep -i ethernet
[    7.494311] alx 0000:05:00.0 eth0: Qualcomm Atheros AR816x/AR817x Ethernet […]
```

### Add Mainline Repository

This step is needed to install a newer kernel. As time of writing this the latest kernel version of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS is `5.15.0`, but the patches only work with some versions. I failed to apply the patches on `5.15.0`. I'm to lazy to compile and build the kernel from the sources.

As described in [Ubuntu Mainline Kernel Installer](https://github.com/bkw777/mainline):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cappelikan/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mainline
```

### Install Kernel 5.16.xx

After adding the Mainline Repository you can install other kernel versions easily:

```
sudo mainline --install 5.16.20
sudo systemctl reboot
```

Note: A list of available versions can be gathered with: `mainline --list`

### Patch the module

Before apply the patch, check the current running kernel version:

```
uname -r
5.16.20-051620-generic
```

Apply the patch:

```
git clone https://github.com/haojunyu/alx_dkms_installer
cd alx_dkms_installer
./setup
```

Note this repository is a fork of the [Upstream / Orign](https://github.com/AMV007/alx_dkms_installer), since the [pull request: feat: add 5.16,support ubuntu22.04](https://github.com/AMV007/alx_dkms_installer/pull/5) is still open. (As time of writing).

Reboot again: `sudo systemctl reboot`

### Check WOL capabilities

```
sudo ethtool enp5s0 | grep -i wake
        Supports Wake-on: pg
        Wake-on: pg
```

I'm able to power on the machine via WoL now. Powered it off and could power it on again via WoL.

### Final Notes

I also tried the `6.0.9` kernel without patching. Still no WoL. I assume there won't be a fix. This hardware is a way of outdated.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll see if I can try this out at some point. And you are probably right with your assessment, but I personally disagree with this being "way outdated". This chip is part of desktop motherboards that are less than 5 years old and really should *not* be phased out so quickly.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution worked for me after WOL stopped working after upgrading from 20.04 to 22.04

in `/etc/tlp.conf` set:

```
WOL_DISABLE=N
```

I believe the cause of my issue was when updating to 22.04 the previously existing `/etc/tlp.conf` file was replaced with a default version which had `#WOL_DISABLE=Y`

original solution source:
https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/wake-on-lan-persistance-issues-22-04/25600/4

additional references:

[Trouble with wakeonlan with Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1244785/trouble-with-wakeonlan-with-ubuntu-20-04)

[wakeonlan with Ubuntu 20.10 stopped working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1313843/wakeonlan-with-ubuntu-20-10-stopped-working)

Comment: This looks okay, but all links are essentially circular "this works" arguments. I've never heard of TLP or `/etc/tlp.conf`, could you add some actual documentation for what it is? In fact, https://linrunner.de/tlp/ mentions this is a battery saving utility, which doesn't make sense in my case (it's a desktop), why would installing this fix it?

Comment: Additionally, it would probably benefit a lot of users if you included what network adapter you have installed e.g., by running `sudo dmesg  | grep -I ethernet`

Comment: For WOL to work, two things are important: that the hardware supports is and is properly set up, and that software doesn't disable it. I did not consciously install tlp on my Ubuntu 22.04 desktop, but it is in fact installed; it is a dependence of the  ubuntu-mate-desktop package.

In /usr/share/tlp/defaults.conf, the line "WOL_DISABLE=Y" is present, so to prevent WOL from being disabled by tlp it is necessary to add the line "WOL_DISABLE=N" to /etc/tlp.conf.

This does explain why WOL broke for me after switching to MATE!  :-)